# Django project using scrapy on windows

Tags: python, django, windows, scrapy

I want to develop a Django project that uses scrapy. I am working on Windows and know that scrapy should be installed on Windows using Anaconda/conda. However, I don't know how to use scrapy installed by conda in my Django project. In Python shell `import scrapy` raises an error message. Is it possible to use Django+scrapy on Windows or I have to switch to Linux?

Comment: did you try to install it via pip ? "pip install scrapy"

Comment: Yep, and that doesn't work for scrapy on windows. It raises a warning regarding TLS/SSL and says "cannot connect to HTTPS URL because the ssl module is not available [...] - skipping"

Answer (score 0):

Not able to comment atm so had to post an answer. This error may be due to Anaconda as referenced here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273 and here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064

It appears to be an issue with the distribution of `conda`, but there doesn't seem to be a definite solution in the threads linked as various solutions have worked for different commenters.